# Retrofit android MultiPart

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

Приложение отправляет изоброжения и несколько строчек. Примерно так (пишу на телефоне. не судите строго) :

```
@Multipar
@POST("url")
Call <Response> senPub (@Part("json") RequestBody json , @Part("image") RequestBody image)
```

Все окей. Успешно отправляется на сервер но проблема в том что получаю я его не в переменной $FILES (django request.FILES) а в $POST. Из-за чего это и как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public interface FileUploadService {  
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part("description") RequestBody description,
                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

}

Подробнее [тут](https://android-school.ru/retrofit-2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80/)